# memoir margins and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, lyx, margins, memoir

I'm trying to use the `hyperref` package with the `memoir` class but the bottom margin of the document is no longer 2 cm as I set it. Rather, it seems like there is no margin at all. When I remove the `hyperref` package, the margins are reset to the correct value. What should I do?
I'm using the `memoir` class in LyX and then I add the following to the preamble:

```
\openany

\midsloppy

\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{babel}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false,AutoSpaceFootnotes=false,AutoSpacePunctuation=false}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider editing the code you provided to show the actual margin-setting commands. As of now, it's not possible to tell how the margins are being set. By the way, the `\raggedbottom` directive allows a page to have a bottom margin that's larger, but no smaller, than the specified value of that parameter.

Comment: I haven't specified any code for the margins in the document. They are set in the dedicated LyX window (Top: 2cm, Bottom: 2cm, Left: 2.5cm, Right: 2.5cm). If I omit the hyperref package, they are preserved. If I add the hyperref, everything is still working, except that the bottom margin is missing. It's like if I have set it to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `hyperref` page size setting can be disabled by

```
\usepackage[setpagesize=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: With more information (MWE, driver, ...) I could investigate further. Usually `hyperref` supports `memoir` and vice versa.