# Wrong box placement depending odd page

Tags: memoir, double-sided

In a two sided memoir document, I'm trying to add a box with an offset in the margin, depending if `\c@page` is odd or not.

It almost works but when this box appears near a page break. In the MWE below, `Écriture` on p. 2 should be on the left margin, while `Histoire` on p. 3 should be on the opposite side.

How to get the correct page number to print the box at the right place?

```
% !TeX TS-encoding = utf8
% !TeX TS-spellcheck = fr_FR
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\matiere}{mO{#1}go}{%
    \vskip \onelineskip
    \ifodd\thepage
    \hspace{\linewidth+6em}\makebox[0pt][r]{\tcbox[
        tcbox raise base,
        boxrule=0.2mm,
        fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
        nobeforeafter,
        colback=blue!3,colframe=blue!50,
        ]{#1 p.~\thepage}}
    \else
    \noindent\hspace{-6em}\makebox[0pt][l]{\tcbox[
        tcbox raise base,
        boxrule=0.2mm,
        fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE,
        nobeforeafter,
        colback=blue!3,colframe=blue!50,
        ]{#1 p.~\thepage}}
    \fi
    \IfValueTF{#3}{\nobreak\section*{#3}%
%        \index[#2]{\thepart \thechapter @#3}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1 — #3}}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
    \IfValueT{#4}{\nobreak #4}
    \sectionmark{#1}
    \vskip 2.3ex \@plus .2ex
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{chapitre}
    \matiere{Calcul}{L'addition}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \matiere{Écriture}[Ecriture]
    \lipsum[3-4]

    \matiere{Géographie}[Geographie]{Les fleuves}
    \lipsum[5]

    \matiere{Histoire}
    \lipsum[6-9]

    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can never reliably test `\thepage` (or better `\value{page}` within the document  you need to set a `\label` and then test the `\pagref` next time (see the zref package for some tests that simplify that a bit)

Comment: Since it is memoir, see its build in facilities for checking the page. I don't have the manual with me, but look up strictpagecheck

Comment: since it's memoir do as @daleif says :-)

Comment: Time to look at the manual and go deeper here for example, I turn it as an answer. Obviously, @daleif can make his own answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @daleif's hint and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162055/151808) it seems to work correctly now.

I just changed the line

```
\ifodd\thepage
```

by

```
\strictpagechecktrue
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
```

Comment: You can place strict... In the preamble, but yes this is the idea. It implements the label feature David mentioned.